# while runnig Applet in the Browser it gives "java.io.FileNotFoundException" exception

Tags: java, json, rest, applet, jersey-client

I have a java applet that is used to upload a file from local machine to a web service server. When I am running it in eclipse it is working fine. But when it is running i the Browser it is giving file not found exception. Anybody any idea why??

////////////////////////HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet code="JarExampleApplet.class" archive="JarExampleApplet.jar" height="200" width="400"></applet>
</body>
</html>
```

/////////////Applet code

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")  
    public class JarExampleApplet extends Applet {

        public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulWS";
        public static final String PATH_NAME = "/file/upload_json/";

        public void init ()
        {
            JarExampleApplet my_client = new JarExampleApplet();
            File file_upload = new File("C:/Grails.pdf");
            try{

            my_client.sendFileJSON(file_upload);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
             System.out.println("Exception : " + ex);
            }   
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawString("This Applet was read from a .jar file.", 0, 25);
        }

        public void sendFileJSON(File file_upload) throws JSONException, IOException{

            ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
            Client client = Client.create(config);
            client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());

            WebResource resource = client.resource(BASE_URI);
            WebResource service = resource.path("rest").path(PATH_NAME);
            JSONObject data_file = new JSONObject();
            data_file.put("file_name", file_upload.getName());
            data_file.put("file", convertFileToString(file_upload));

            ClientResponse client_response = service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, data_file);
            System.out.println(" "+client_response);
            System.out.println("Status: "+client_response.getStatus());

            client.destroy();

        }


        //Convert my file to a Base64 String
        private String convertFileToString(File file) throws IOException{
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());   
            return new String(Base64.encode(bytes));
        }
    }
```

Comment: share full stack trace of exception. I think your file path `File file_upload = new File("C:/Grails.pdf");` is not correct

Comment: An applet is a poor choice for this, applets typically exist within a tight security model which prevents them from, amongst other things, accessing the local disk

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 24 more

Comment: @AniketKumar Check this [url](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml) regarding java security.

Comment: @learningloop I have tried all the security setting, the applet is running on the browser but giving runtime exception "ClassNotFoundException:com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig" this time.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is there any way by which a file in local machine can be uploaded to a web server automatically??

Comment: Yes, but not via an applet (or more precisely, not easily).  You'd have to install some kind of service or have the user run a program locally

Comment: @MadProgrammer actually I have case where a website is opening in the iframe of our website,there is a link which opens a pdf file in the Browser. I have to upload that pdf file to the server.For that I have made a chrome extention but it is downloading it to my local machine.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Any idea how to do this job.